# Why does the final kill cam only show up sometimes in objective games?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops

It seems like the final kill cam in Black Ops only shows up reliably in death match type games.

What determines if the final kill cam is displayed or not in objective games (Domination, CtF, etc)?

If it matters I'm mainly talking about xbox live's multiplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply for entertainment.  The game watches for the last kill before the objective was completed (not sure how much earlier it can be) and displays it as the final kill.  If there were no last kills, theres no final kill cam

Comment: I get that, I would like to know what the criteria of that final kill is. It is sort of important for a number of challenges, and I find it really annoying to do something cool and not have it displayed.

Answer (score 3):

If the winning point in a match is a kill, it will show the final kill cam.

For objective type matches you can gain points by capturing flags AND getting kills. If the final point in the match was a flag capture (or gaining points over time intervals while holding a flag), no final kill cam will be played. If it ended in a kill, it will play.

Comment: i have sometimes seen losing team guy killing the winning team guy in the kill-cam, how would that be possible?

Comment: That's not true. The killcam shows also in objective type games, where kills don't achieve anything directly.

Answer (score 1):

i think it has to be whithin 3 to 5 seconds before the match ends or the final kill in a kill limit type match.